# When I press tab for autocomplete in bash I get: "Cannot parse arguments: unknown option -r"

Tags: bash, autocomplete

My tab key's autocomplete function is not working. 
Instead, it spits out this error message: `Cannot parse arguments: unknown option -r`

Comment: Take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you run `set -x`, the shell will print everything it is running, so you can figure out what command is malformed.  Then if you run `complete` with no arguments, you can also see what completion commands have been configured.  One of them obviously has a syntax error.